# A bijective transform that cycles. Help with definitions requested

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, group-theory

In many ways I am a novice with mathematics. My background is college algebra.
 I am attempting to write my first maths paper and am faced with sifting through mathematics I am not familiar with. It has been 20 years since I was in college but I digress.

What I have is a algorithm that transforms finite length binary strings into the next element in that cycle. Also it reverses so it is bijective.
 This seems different from group theory, from what I can tell, since to be called a group it should use two elements to produce a third.
 Permutation cycle also seems to fail since that is an ordering.

I am seeing the idea of spin (physics) to be close in that both directions of rotations exist with this bijective transform.
 The symbol that seems to be correct to use is lower case sigma  σ. Is that a correct usage for a cycle of elements? A cycle of one element to the next... and back around to the first.

Would I use circular notation? Length = 6 bits ( a₁ .... a₆) ? Where σ(a₁) = a(a₂) and σ(a₁₊k) = (a¹) k=6 for example. 
What would signal direction if this is the correct form? 
 I have seen capital sigma ∑ used with a modifier in the middle such as a circle or other symbol, which was defined in context of the paper, to represent the action that caused the cycle of elements in a similar transform.

I wish to follow standard notation if possible. I believe a novice should learn the strict forms before he invents anew.

I appreciate your time.

Ernst

Comment: It looks just like the group $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ on addition.

Comment: Thank You ml0105. Would you be so kind as to point me to a proper reference I may study. My initial look-up is confusing although I did find a .pdf http: [link]http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhoqaibi.kau.edu.sa%2FGetFile.aspx%3Fid%3D61821%26fn%3Dnote1foraalgebra.pdf&ei=_KAsU5zeK4PGoASfq4DABw&usg=AFQjCNESc7oxPiD6fpFe4gMvsJTVMI4qGA&sig2=cedbgXPjFOKGP9Ch1SsdfA&bvm=bv.63316862,d.cGU&cad=rja

Answer (score 0):

I'll expand more here on $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. This group is defined on equivalence classes, partitioned around the elements $\{0, 1, 2, ..., n-1\}$. Two integers are said to be congruent if they have the same remainder modulo $n$. That is, $a \equiv b$ $(mod$ $n)$ if and only if $n | (a - b)$.

So as an example, $10 \equiv 1$ $(mod$ $3)$. We also have $-1 \equiv n-1$ $(mod$ $n)$.

There are a few more examples and a bit on the Euclidean Algorithm here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237418-introduction-to-modular-arithmetic-and-euclidean-algorithm/

What you really want to take away though is this: you increment the index. If you go beyond the bounds, you cycle around to the beginning. This is how addition works on the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Comment: It may be a silly question but what is meant by n|(a−b)? Is it a restriction, a division or statement such as? I am that green my friend. Thank You

Comment: It's a division statement. $p|q$ states that there is an integer $k$ such that $pk = q$. It is assumed $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$.